# What is the meaning of "Mure"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Today, education has become a priority for **many parents seeking to secure a good Mure for their children** in this rapidly changing world. They believe that if their children apply themselves and work hard at school, then they will increase their opportunities for going to higher education and eventually getting a good job. Of course they are right, and as access to the best education and best jobs is becoming more competitive, then it is true that children have to make the best of their study time when they are young.

This paragraph is from IELTS Cambridge book 3, from a writing sample prepared by an examiner as a very good answer.

I checked Longman Dictionary and it did not have "Mure". I then checked the net and it says "something resembling a wall" which does not make sense to me in this context.

Comment: +1 for telling us where the text is from and what you found when you looked for an answer before posting your question. Details like those are very helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about some kind of typesetting or OCR / transcription error. The original text was obviously *...seeking to secure a good **future** for their children~*.

Comment: It is a waste of time searching  for the meaning of  Mure. It is a mistake

Comment: I once read a science fiction story involving the "Three Laws of Robotics", one of which says "A robot may not injure a human being". A robot kills a human being, and when it is questioned afterwards, says "Oh no! I thought it said 'a robot may not _immure_ a human being!"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a typographical or transcription error unlikely to be encountered by future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

It's a mistake. The word should be **future**.

> Today, education has become a priority for many parents seeking to secure a good future for their children in this rapidly changing world.

Here's a [link](https://www.ielts-mentor.com/writing-sample/writing-task-2/329-ielts-writing-task-2-sample-103-children-s-leisure-activities-must-be-educational) that contains the text, without the error.

Comment: It's an OCR error, then? The 'fut' of '**fut**ure' being rendered as a capital M?